# Install Apache Module mod_systemd

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I am installating the Apache Module **mod_systemd**. I am using Arch Linux.
I have no idea where and how to start.

Comment: What makes you think you actually need this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, we describe:

- How to download and compile Apache trunk version (it is the first version with **mod_systemd**).
- How to compile Apache with signatures of an older version.

When this answer was posted, the trunk version was `Apache 2.5`

## Download and compile Apache trunk version

I recommend to do this in a `testing environment`. I've tested it on a `debian minbase wheezy` system. For `arch linux` the package names should be similar and instead of `apt-get`, `pacman` should be used. The `configure` script will prompt all missing build dependencies anyway.

#### Install build dependencies (debian minbase wheezy example)

```
apt-get install subversion
apt-get install autoconf
apt-get install libtool
apt-get install python
apt-get install libexpat1-dev
apt-get install libpcre3-dev
apt-get install libsystemd-daemon-dev
apt-get install g++
apt-get install make
```

#### Download apache development source code

```
mkdir trunk
cd trunk
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk ./
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr
```

#### Configure apache

```
./buildconf
./configure --enable-systemd
```

#### Build and install

```
make
make install
```

#### Enable mod_systemd

```
echo "LoadModule systemd_module modules/mod_systemd.so" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

#### Check enabled modules

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -M
```

## Compile Apache with signatures of an older version

If you want to use **mod_systemd** in an older version of Apache, you may try to compile `Apache 2.5` with other version's signatures.

#### Check which version of Apache you have

```
apachectl -v
```

#### Download the source code of your Apache version

https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

#### Uncompress its contents

```
tar xf httpd-version.tar.gz
```

#### Copy the signature's file to the trunk version folder

```
cp httpd-version/include/ap_mmn.h ~/trunk/include/
```

#### Compile the trunk version with other version's signatures

```
cd ~/trunk
make
```

#### Copy mod_systemd wherever you want

```
find . -name mod_systemd.so -exec cp {} destination/ \;
```

Comment: can you be more specific?I have mentioned my distribution. where can I find the actual module to download? secondly, I am using apache 2.4 and in the docs it does not mention any where about the version this mod needs

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Sure :D ↑

Comment: This may be the way to do it on debian, but it is a terrible idea for Arch...

Comment: @edwardtorvalds why?

Comment: Where to begin? Apache is only at 2.4.18 so he will have trouble finding a distro with 2.5. Arch's build system is *nothing* like Debians and, even if it was, using make install for something like Apache is a foolish thing to suggest...

Comment: @jasonwryan you have no other choice and there may be some unstable/testing distros with apache 2.5 :D

Comment: @ncomputers.org I appreciate the answer, even it does not applies to Arch (because it cant right) please dont delete the answer. I will try to do this on arch and see if it works, thanks

Comment: @ncomputers.org second question, does this module comes with apache source code?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds yes, more precisely: `modules/arch/unix/mod_systemd.c` it is better to use a `testing environment`, because `Apache 2.5` is under development...

Comment: @edwardtorvalds here the source of `mod_systemd` http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/arch/unix/mod_systemd.c

Comment: @ncomputers.org cant we build this module separately ? and insert in already install apache ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds It could be. Just consider that it was built for `Apache 2.5` I'am starting testing with `Apache 2.2`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I've tried it with `Apache 2.2` and got this error: `undefined symbol: ap_get_sload` now trying with `Apache 2.4`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35706/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-ncomputers-org).

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I could successfully install `mod_systemd` compiled for `Apache 2.5` in `Apache 2.4` .... which exact version of `Apache 2.4` are you using? You can see it with `apachectl -v`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use apache25 (and php-apache25, if you need PHP) from AUR.

https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/apache25/

https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/php-apache25/